# Deal with requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock and NSDictionary. Convert any type to NSString without knowing what exactly it is

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *str = nil;
NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:(const char*)attr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
str = [attributionDetails valueForKey:key];
```

In this case, I want to convert [attributionDetails valueForKey:key] into NSString. But I don't know what exactly it is, maybe ints or strings or booleans, I just want them all to be converted to NSString. So how can I solve this problem?

Update:

```
 NSString* key = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:(const char*)attr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSObject* obj = [attributionDetails valueForKey:key];
    NSString* str = (NSString*)obj;
```

Can I solve the problem in this way？I pass the value no matter what type to a NSObject and then convert the NSObject to NSString.

Update2:
The whole method is below. Will it work?

```
char* _getIad(char* attr)
{
    NSString* str = nil;
    [[ADClient sharedClient] requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock: 
        ^(NSDictionary *attributionDetails, NSError *error) 
        {
            if(error.code == ADClientErrorLimitAdTracking) 
            { 
                return; 
            }
            if(!error)
            {
                NSString* key = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:(const char*)attr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSObject* obj = [attributionDetails valueForKey:key];
                str = (NSString*)obj;
            }
            return;
        }];
    return strdup([str UTF8String]);
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the results to be formatted given that you don't know what they are? You can call `-description` on the object to get it into a string, but that doesn't mean that the result will be in a format that is useful to you...

Comment: @Itai Ferber Well, attributionDetails is an object of NSDictionary, and  it may contain ints, strings and booleans.That's what I know. But I want a common approach to pass the value to a NSString object no matter what type the value is. And I  just need to store the  value, not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

creat a mathod or category, just use if xx is NSString class, else if nil , or booleans, then return the convert value

Answer (score 0):

Every type which descends from the class `NSObject` implements the protocol `NSObject`, and that protocol has the method:

> `description`
>
> **Required**. Returns a string that describes the contents of the receiver.

So it get your string you can just do:

```
str = attributionDetails[key].description;
```

The string returned by `description` is for *display* purposes, there is no requirement that it is easy to parse back into the value it is describing, but as you "just need to store the value, not to use it" it should suffice.

HTH

Comment: To be clear, the output of `description` should never be used for display to the user. It should only be used for debugging. And you must never rely on its format. It can change in any iOS update.

Comment: What if attributionDetails[key] is kind of primitive types？Do they descend from NSObject?

Comment: @Frank.W - an `NSDictionary` (or any NS collection class) **only** contains object types. For a primitive type to be in such a collection it must be wrapped as an object, e.g. `NSNumber`.

Comment: @rmaddy - I think this is a good recommendation rather than an absolute rule, for debugging purposes there is the optional protocol method `debugDescription`. That said while it is not clear why the OP is seeking this string conversion it doesn't appear to be for UI purposes.